# Laravel Request::Ajax() not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to learn the Laravel Ajax request.

`route.php`

```
    Route::get('/repository/', 'RepositoryController@index');
    Route::post('/repository/', function(){
        if(Request::ajax()){
            return 'Got everything';
        }
    });
```

and

`repository.index.php` I have a modal which is appearing upon clicking a button on the same page with the following markup

```
@section('popups')
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" name="name">
      </div>
        <a href="#" id="add">Submit</a>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('.add').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); 

           var name=$(this).find('input[name=name]').val();

           //post Ajax
           $.post('/repository', {name:name}, function(data){
              console.log(data);
           });
        });


    });
</script>

@stop
```

Now, it looks like I cannot get the data in the console. What is the best way to send the data to the database? and if there is error in validation how can I show it in the model itself?

Comment: Just a note - you don't need to declare your routes with the slashes: `Route::get('repository'...` and `Route::post('repository',...` are enough

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that. Any idea about the problem here?

Comment: It looks like it should work.. are you loading jquery ok?

Comment: yes, it is loading very well. Otherwise the popup wouldnt work. Right

Comment: right!  I just tested your code and it's working here... silly question, but no errors in the console?  can you see the request in your web server logs?

Comment: Nope, it shows no error. Can you show your code in a jsfiddle? I'm testing it on the localhost

Comment: ah.. in your JS you're looking for something with `class="add"`, but your <a> has `id="add"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jQuery selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add').click(function(e){ // id=add
       e.preventDefault(); 

       var name=$(this).find('input[name=name]').val();

       //post Ajax
       $.post('/repository', {name:name}, function(data){
          console.log(data);
       });
    });
});
```

You're looking for a class in your original code, whereas the anchor has an id!  :)

Comment: oh yeah!!! Silly me. Also, how about validating this fields in the model? just like the normal procedures? Will it show the error in the model itself?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'll have to update your modal with JS, but really it would be better to give it a try and ask a new question if you get stuck!  good luck!  :)

Comment: Sure. Once again, Thanks :)